# .gemrc comments?

Tags: ruby, comments, rubygems, rc

This is a basic question

Are comments allowed in the `.gemrc` file?

If so how would you do them?

I checked here to no avail

[docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/11](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/11)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The doc says: [`The config file itself is in ’’’YAML’’’ format.`](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/11)

This means you can have [comments starting with #](http://yaml.org/spec/current.html#id2502724), eg:

```
# I like docs
rdoc: --inline-source --line-numbers
```